# Can't add a new iOS version for my app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

See the picture.  My app is "Ready for Sale", and I have a new version.  Do I have to upload a version at 1.0.1? The version I want to upload is 1.3.7.

**iOS version is disabled:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 4):

You can only have one released version and one pending version per platform.

In your case you have a pending 0.2.2 release, so you can’t add another.

What you can do is go into that release and change the version number to your desired version (1.3.7) and then upload a build for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pending version numbers as you have already a version is pending to release i.e. "0.2.2".
Hope this will work for you.